# Updating htaccess file, Google Maps disabled

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to update my .htaccess file in wordpress. But after updating the .htaccess file, my google map disappear.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what did you add to .htaccess ? I assume there maybe another problem not .htaccess itself unless you have added something strange to .htaccess that blocks for instance js files or ...

Comment: the map is just appear for a second and when i scroll down it disappear again.

Comment: so it's not htaccess problem, there maybe a css or js related problem

Comment: but after removing htaccess file it work fine.

Comment: so just paste your .htaccess code here let's see ,

Comment: you can edit your post and add .htaccess content as well as adding a demo of the page if possible or sample code of your map page if would help a lot.

Comment: that is a plugin and that comes from a widget.

Comment: without seeing it's hard to debug, Like I said if you want help you must provide more details